# Is it possible to strip the extra characters around this note in SQL Server?

Tags: html, css, sql, parsing, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working in the database for Manager Plus on SQL Server 2008 R2. The user wants to see the note associated with a work order on a report, but the note is surrounded by what might either be CSS or HTML.

> {\rtf1\ansi\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil Tahoma;}}  {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}  {*\generator Riched20 10.0.15063}\viewkind4\uc1   \pard\widctlpar\f0\fs22\lang1033 Troubleshooting two wires was disconnected and was connected back inside of the power supply. Also working with the outside technicians.\line\par    \pard\cf1\f1\fs16\par  }

The real note starts with "Troubleshooting" and ends with "technicians.". Is there a way in SQL to parse out the note itself?

Comment: It's not impossible, but SQL is not the right tool for this job. String manipulation will most likely be easier to write, read and maintain in a programming language, and will probably have better performance as well.

Comment: This is MS .rtf format. You need a .rtf capable tool for that.